# d/m/y to Y-m-d php stringtotime not working correctly

Tags: php, date, explode

I have a date string of the format `d/m/y` e.g. `22/02/13`

I would like to echo this string as `Y-m-d` but using the following code, it is not working.

```
$d = '22/02/13';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($d));
```

Output: `1970-01-01`

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to explode this by `/` as the delimiter and do it manually or is there a simpler / more elegant solution?

Comment: `22/02/13 !== 22-02-13`. In the first you have m/d/Y and in the second d-m-Y. Seem a location validation inside the core of PHP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use DateTime:

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', '22/02/13');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KjGLlj)

**Reference**

- [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Answer (score 4):

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> Note:
>
> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)
>   dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

**tl;dr:** If you use slashes it will take it as a m/d/y crazy American style date.

Easiest work around is to use the [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to create your own format:

```
$date= DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', '21/11/13');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: +1 for "use `createFromFormat`". I don't know why people persist in using the `strtotime()` function when `createFromFormat` is available. I guess people are still learning PHP from web tutorials that were written in the previous decade.

Answer (score 4):

Using `/` makes PHP think you're using the American style formatting of a date (`mm/dd/yy`), so replace them with dashes for the required output:

```
$d = str_replace('/', '-', '22/02/13');
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($d));
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at

```
DateTime::createFromFormat(...)
```

This will create a correct DateTime value.

Answer (score 0):

Easier way:

```
$d = '22.02.13';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($d));
```

Saludos ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo implode("-", array_reverse(explode('/', $val)));
```

Answer (score 0):

For this

*"Note:
Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.
To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible."*

http://php.net/strtotime